# Use XPath to find links containing two things

Tags: html, xpath, contains

I'm using XPath to parse an HTML document to find a specific link. The specific link has a domain name in it and the character '@'.

```
//a[@*[contains(., 'domain')]] | //a[@*[contains(., '@')]]"
```

Will return links with 'domain' OR '@' in them and I need 'domain' AND '@'

I've been trying to use:

```
//a[@*[contains(., 'domain')]] & //a[@*[contains(., '@')]]"
```

But that's no good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about XPath operators [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp). The `&` operator does not exist.
Also, there is no need to select the element twice.
You could use either

```
//a[@*[contains(., 'domain')]][@*[contains(., '@')]]
```

or

```
//a[@*[contains(., 'domain')] and @*[contains(., '@')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be as easy as:

```
//a[@*[contains(., 'domain')]][@*[contains(., '@')]]
```